# $p>2$ & $p$ prime, $p-1=q_1^{c_1}\cdots q_g^{c_g}$ where the $q_i$ are distinct primes...

Tags: number-theory

and the $c_i$ are positive integers. Let $a \in \{1,2,\dots,p-1\}$. Show that if an integer 
$x < p-1$ divides $p-1$ then $x$ must divide at least one of $d_1,d_2,\dots,d_g$, where $d_j = \frac{p-1}{q_j}$.

I mean it seems obvious…

Here's an example:
$$p = 11, \quad p - 1 = 10 = 5\cdot 2$$

$$5\mid 5\cdot 2 \text{ and } 5\mid 10/5.$$

I feel like this is like an algebra problem is a sense but not sure. I wouldn't know how to grab a random $d_j$ etc. 
Maybe a proof by contradiction?

Comment: Begin at the beginning. What on Earth is the title of this thing supposed to mean?

Comment: I had no idea to make a title for this...
x|(p-1) ==> x|$q_1^{c_1}***q_g^{c_g}$. Well x is not prime so I can't split these up.
Dividing both sides by...

Answer (score 1):

The (positive) divisors of $p-1=q_1^{c_1}\cdots q_g^{c_g}$ all have shape $q_1^{e_1}\cdots q_g^{e_g}$ where $e_i\le c_i$ for all $i$. Since $p-1\gt 1$, not all the $c_i$ are $0$.

Since $x\lt p-1$, not all the $e_i$ are equal to $c_i$. Assume in particular that $e_j\lt c_j$. Then $e_j\le c_{j}-1$, and therefore $x$ divides $\frac{p-1}{q_j}$.